# How can I give api authentication from existing web middleware login in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I have a existing admin panel in a *laravel* based web application. I made few part of this admin panel in *vue.js* single page application. I don't wanted to use token based authentication for this spa part of this application. How can I give api authentication from my existing session login system.

Comment: you can use laravel passport to authenticate your api and then use https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript to use web session for authenticate

Comment: @rkj that would be overkill for what is being asked

Comment: @Quezler i don't think it is good to add `StartSession` middleware in api, lets the things keep separate, so that in future if he needs to access api he can easily

Answer (score 2):

Change the `auth:api` middleware to just `auth` in `./routes/api.php`

And in `./app/Http/Kernel.php` `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` to the `middlewareGroups` array under `api`

Comment: or alternatively, just change `->middleware('api')` to `->middleware('web')` in the `mapApiRoutes` fuction in `./app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

Comment: I know that. but is there any another way to keep api middleware and use cookie for authentication. i don't wanted to use `web` middleware. Thanks

Comment: the authentication done in laravel web routes is the `SessionGuard`, in order to use that for api route authentication you need need to add the `StartSession` middleware to the api routes as explained in the answer, you can ignore the alternative in the comment :)

Comment: If you add `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` to `api` part of `middlewareGroups` array you also need to add `\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class` before it.